# How to handle KeyTooLongError Node.js(AWS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get some images from my S3 server, but some of them have really large URLs. How could I download those images even with the large URL?

Code:

```
//download the object from the bucket
sourceS3.getObject(getparamsOrig, function(gerr, s3obj) {
    if (gerr) {
        //if there is problem just print to console and move on.
        console.log('Download issue');
        console.log(gerr);
        return;
    }   
});
```

Debug:

```
DEBUG [03314cb6]    Download issue
DEBUG [03314cb6]    { [KeyTooLongError: Your key is too long]
DEBUG [03314cb6]      message: 'Your key is too long',
DEBUG [03314cb6]      code: 'KeyTooLongError',
DEBUG [03314cb6]      time: Tue Apr 21 2015 17:10:51 GMT-0400 (EDT),
DEBUG [03314cb6]      statusCode: 400,
DEBUG [03314cb6]      retryable: false }
```

Comment: Are you sure that a key actually exists with that name? This shouldn't be possible.